# android save/reload settings

Tags: android, settings, android-actionbar

in my app, I have 2 activities, first is actionbar with list in each page, and the second one is settings activity, in which you can set, how many and which tabs actionbar contains. everything works, but last thing, that I cant get done is, how to get back to first activity, when I set settings and click button. I dont want to pass intent and start activity as new, because JSONRpc client is at start and it takes while to connect etc, and that would be annoying. I tried finish() second activity and call setActionBar onResume(), but that ist working... any ideas?? thanks.. heres some code:

first activity:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 Rubriky = ((HNapp) this.getApplication()).getRubriky();
 count=((HNapp) this.getApplication()).getCount(); 

 int catIndex = savedInstanceState == null ? 0 :savedInstanceState.getInt("catIndex", 0);
 setUpActionBar(catIndex);
 }
 //my try
 public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onResume();
    int catIndex = savedInstanceState == null ? 0 : savedInstanceState.getInt("catIndex", 0);
    Rubriky = ((HNapp) this.getApplication()).getRubriky();
    count=((HNapp) this.getApplication()).getCount();
    setUpActionBar(catIndex);
}

 //setting up actionbar
 public void setUpActionBar(int selTab) {

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    CABNavHan handler = new CABNavHan(this);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(Rubriky[i]).setTabListener(handler));
        }
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(selTab);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you verified that count is updating onResume as you would expect (assuming that when you finish() the settings activity it returns to the existing action in the back stack)?
2. I notice that onResume you are doing the same behaviour on the already populated UI objects. Is it possible that the ActionBar for this UI instance is already configured and you need to update it rather than re-creating it? It's hard to tell from the code snippet you have provided.

Comment: well you could store a reference to it near where you define count (as a member variable) with "ActionBar actionBar;". Then assign it onCreate and mutate the existing instance in onResume

Answer (score 0):

call onBackPressed(); where u want to go back to
 1st avtivity.

Comment: why emulate the UI input instead of calling final(); is there a functional difference or benefit?

Comment: I think final and onBackpressed() both are different. he dont want to pass intent, so calling onBackPressed with retrive the previous activity

Comment: I thought calling final() would cause Android to finalize your current Activity (a product of calling onBackPressed()) and return to the next activity on the stack (effectively going back).

Comment: No. I am not sure, try this public void onResume(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onResume();
onBackPressed();}

Comment: but onbackpressed is called when user press BACK button, isnt it?